# AboutHeader.jsx:21 Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to do a state change that will change the className after setTimeout, however, I keep getting a "AboutHeader.jsx:21 Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function" I've tried binding (this) but it still won't work.
import React from 'react';

require('../../stylesheets/component/AboutHeader.scss');

export default class AboutHeader extends React.Component {

```
constructor() {
    super()
this.timeDelay = this.timeDelay.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        class: "about-header-wrapper-hidden"
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
console.log("mounted");
    this.timeDelay();
}
```

timeDelay() {
    setTimeout(function updateState(){this.setState({class: "about-header-wrapper"})}, 1000);
    console.log("timeDelay worked");
  }

```
render() {
    return (
        <section className={this.state.class}></section>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `.bind(this)` on the `setTimout()`. [Here's your code in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pimeha/edit?js,console) with binding `this`. If you remove it, it throws the error.

```js
setTimeout(function updateState() {
  this.setState({ class: "about-header-wrapper" })
}.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I knew I had to bind "this" but I kept failing. So thank you very much.